# ucanaccess jdbc connection without IDE

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am trying to make a basic JDBC program using MS Access. I downloaded the Ucanacess.zip file and I got in total 6 .jar files namely: 
**ucanaccess-3.0.7,
ucanload,
commons-lang-2.6,
commons-logging-1.1.1,
hsqldb, and
jackcess-2.1.3**

I added them to the classpath as Environment Variables(Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variable).

But when I run my Code it gives an Exception
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver**

Here is the code

```
class DB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you run your code (what is the **exact** command line you use)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run :

- javac DB.java
- java -cp . -cp  ucanaccess-3.0.7.jar -cp ucanload.jar ... DB

The former to compile DB.java.
The latter to run java by setting classpath, "." is the directory where resides the compiled "DB.class"

Comment: Instead of specifying `-cp` multiple times, you can also do it once and separate the jars by `;` (Windows) or `:` (Linux and Mac)

Comment: Now it's telling me that it was not able to find or load main class DB. Here is the command: **java -cp . -cp  ucanaccess-3.0.7.jar;ucanload.jar;commons-lang-2.6.jar;commons-logging-1.1.1.jar; hsqldb.jar; jackcess-2.1.3 DB**

Comment: what is package declaration of DB class ? if no package you must be in the foldaer containing DB.class.

Comment: They are already in the same folder.